# ionic 5 alert buttons with JavaScript

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5, typescript

Without using any Javascript framework or Class, I am working with pure Javascript and Ionic 5 .
I am trying to display the alert notification when the user hit the *Add* button
If the User does not fill the fields and then press the ADD Button, an alert pops out to notify the user to fill the fields

Note: Add button its function also is to Add two fields

The issue is when Hit the Add button, No notification pops out

here is the code

**HTML section**

```
<ion-alert-controller></ion-alert-controller>
```

In app.js file

```
    const btnConfirm = document.querySelector('#btn-confirm');
    const alertCtrl = document.querySelector('ion-alert-contrller');

    btnConfirm.addEventListener('click' ,() => {
 
  const enterReason = reasonInput.value;
 
 const enterInput = parseFloat(amountInput.value).toFixed(2);

   if(enterReason.trim().length <=0 || enterInput <= 0 || enterInput.trim().length <=0
   
   ) {

      async function handleButtonClick() {

         const alert = await alertController.create({
          message: 'Please enter valid reason and amount!',
          header: 'Invalid Inputs',
          buttons: ['Okay']
         });

         await alert.present();

          
      }

       return; // if values are Invalid - stop execution
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do somethign like:

```
const btnConfirm = document.querySelector('#btn-confirm');

    btnConfirm.addEventListener('click' ,() => {
      
      const enterReason = reasonInput.value;
      const enterInput = parseFloat(amountInput.value).toFixed(2);

      if(enterReason.trim().length <=0 || enterInput <= 0 || enterInput.trim().length <=0) {

          presentAlert(); // call your alert function when input is invalid
          return;

      }else{
        // continue execution
      }

    })

// keep your alert as a function. and call it when ever you want. 

    async function presentAlert() { 
      const alert = document.createElement('ion-alert');
      alert.cssClass = 'my-custom-class';
      alert.header = 'Alert';
      alert.subHeader = 'Subtitle';
      alert.message = 'This is an alert message.';
      alert.buttons = ['OK'];

      document.body.appendChild(alert);
      await alert.present();

      const { role } = await alert.onDidDismiss();
      console.log('onDidDismiss resolved with role', role);
    }
```